# SyntaxError when parsing JSON from loadUrl in WebView

Tags: javascript, android

I am passing JSON from Java to the WebView like this:

```
JSONObject _res = new JSONObject(response);
webView.loadUrl("javascript:receive('"+url+"', '"+_res.toString()+"')");
```

In JavaScript I have a corresponding function:

```
function receive(url, data){
    if(_callbacks[url] && data){
        _callbacks[url](JSON.parse(data));
        delete _callbacks[url];
        hideSpinner();
    }
}
```

The JSON.parse() in JS fails with "Web Console﹕ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".
Could it be an encoding problem? I am also sure that the provided JSON string is valid.

Here's an example call taken from LogCat:

```
javascript:receive('mm://content/%7B%22id%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22city_id%22%3A0%7D', '{"title":"test","body":"<p>Foo<\/p>\r\n<p>Bar<\/p>","menu":[]}')
```

And heres the full error:

```
E/Web Console﹕ Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL at file:///android_asset/htdocs/index.html#welcome:1
```

Comment: JSON.parse is very strict, your JSON string might be valid but maybe you can share an example with us as this is exactly where it is throwing the error.

Comment: I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

According to me in your case you should double escape the CR and LF.
   `JSON.parse('{"title":"test","body":"<p>Foo<\/p>\\r\\n<p>Bar<\/p>","menu":[]}')`

I don't know what would let you do it in java but before sending it from the server you should find a way to escape those.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but the answer on it doesn't help.

The answer comes from [addJavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)), "developer.android" helps aren't always easy to understand, so for this case the proper answer with a example for the problem to pass a json object from Java to javascript on webview using loadUrl is:

```
JSONObject _res = new JSONObject(response);
String url = "mm://content/%7B%22id%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22city_id%22%3A0%7D";

class WebAppInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String Get_res_toString() {
        return _res.toString();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String Get_url() {
        return url;
    }
}

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
webView.loadUrl("javascript:receive(Android.Get_url(), Android.Get_res_toString())");
```

The strings received on js side will be the same as printed on the logcat and will not throw any "error" when parsed (of course as long the json object was properly created).

More about how that [WebAppInterface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) works.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing data through the loadUrl to JavaScript, use the loadUrl to call another function on the Android side which can return the data to the JavaScript